# Is this a better way to summarize the Synopsis of the find command?

Tags: find

In the man page for `find` I find the following in the synopsis:

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [expression]
```

But after reading the man page I find it to be more like:

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [options] [tests] [actions]
```

Is my understanding of this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your synopsis suggests that options must come before tests and both options and tests must come before actions, but that is not true. In fact, they can go in any order.

Furthermore, there is fundamentally no difference between what the GNU `find` manpage calls tests and what it calls actions. I don't know why the manpage categorizes them differently in the text (note that manpages for non-GNU versions of `find` don't distinguish), but it's probably for convenience and for ease of explanation. In fact, actions are really just tests, they just happen to have side effects. Notice that all of the so-called actions are documented to have a boolean return value, just like so-called tests (although many of them just unconditionally return true). The evaluation of the whole expression is affected by these return values, and the order matters just like it does with "real" tests (especially when parentheses and logic operators like `-o` are involved). Also, even so-called options are actually tests too (from the manpage: "All options always return true."). Therefore it would be misleading to suggest in the synopsis that these are syntactically different things.

Comment: It's not a real good idea to put `-delete` first though (as far as I can tell from the man page: `Don't forget that the find command line is evaluated as an expression, so putting -delete first will make find try to delete everything below the starting points you specified.`) could that be the reason the documentation is written as such?

Comment: It's the same as, say, putting `-ls` first, it's just that putting `-delete` first is a more... destructive... mistake. :-) I believe that if you understand that the arguments to `find` all form one big expression, you are more likely to understand how `find` really works and less likely to make that mistake. If you think that actions are separate from tests and don't form part of the expression, it can *lead* to that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Using your terminology, *options*, *tests* and *actions* can be intermixed:

```
find / -type f -name '*.DELETE' -ls -delete -o -name '*.COMPRESS' -exec gzip {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't know you could use `-name` as an AND as such.

Comment: AND/OR rather...